# Convert multiple columns with string in (hh:mm:ss) format to seconds (int) in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 15 columns, 9 of them are strings in duration format (hh:mm:ss) that I need to convert them into seconds (int).
I am still new with pandas and python and wrote the below code.

```
#Example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['00:12:21','01:20:01'],'column_2':['00:22:33','02:10:11']})

def duration_to_sec(x):
    
    if len(x.split(':')) == 3 :
        h,m,s = x.split(':')
        x = (int(h)*60*60)+(int(m)*60)+(int(s))
    else : x=0
    return x

new_col = []
for i in df['column_1']:
    x = duration_to_sec(i)
    new_col.append(x)

df['column_1'] = pd.Series(new_col)
print(df)
```

> Expected output (same as column_1)

```
   column_1  column_2
0       741  00:22:33
1      4801  02:10:11
```

it is working fine but it is really basic and I have to declare the function multiple times for the 9 columns. so what is the simpler and cleaner methods to apply here?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example as DataFrame constructor and the matching expected output.

Comment: I provided a minimal example 'df', I need to convert 9 columns in the data frame to be as the expected output i mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conversion [`to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html), then [`total_seconds`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html):

```
df['column_1'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['column_1']).dt.total_seconds():
```

Output:

```
   column_1  column_2
0     741.0  00:22:33
1    4801.0  02:10:11
```

##### converting multiple columns:

```
def to_sec(s):
    return pd.to_timedelta(s).dt.total_seconds()

out = df.apply(to_sec)
```

Output:

```
   column_1  column_2
0     741.0    1353.0
1    4801.0    7811.0
```

Comment: thanks! this is working great, can i iterate it over multiple columns I specify though ? can iterate by column name or order

Comment: Check the second part to apply to multiple columns. Subset if needed and update the DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through a list of column names if needed:

```
for col in ('column_1', 'column_2'): # Put all your columns that need conversion.
    df[col] = pd.to_timedelta(df[col])
    df[f'{col}_seconds'] = df[col].dt.total_seconds()
```

Output:

```
         column_1        column_2  column_1_seconds  column_2_seconds
0 0 days 00:12:21 0 days 00:22:33             741.0            1353.0
1 0 days 01:20:01 0 days 02:10:11            4801.0            7811.0
```